# JavaScript returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have the following JSON that I receive from a URL, we call the URL here `www.blabla.com/testjson`

And it returns:

```
[{"Identifier":1,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"Kopenhagen 9","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"NOT Given","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"},
    {"Identifier":2,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 1","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Rotterdam","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"},
    {"Identifier":3,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 6","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Rotterdam","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"},
    {"Identifier":4,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 1","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Den Haag","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"},
    {"Identifier":5,"Naam":"NOT Given","Adres":"NOT Given 218","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Zoetermeer","Longitude":"0.00000","Latitude":"0.00000"}
];
```

I want to retrieve this JSON en return this result, but I get UNDEFINED, this is my code:

```
$.each("www.blabla.com/testjson", function(index, element) {
    $('.result').append(element.Naam);
    alert(element.Naam);
});
```

You also need to check if the user cookies are true or else it won't return something, I don't do this because I work with phonegap and jquery mobile. Can that be the problem?

Comment: In this case, I assume, `$.each` will iterate over the each character of the string. And strings don't have a property `Naam` (that's why you get `undefined`).  It won't execute an AJAX request. Please have a look again at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/.

Comment: can you provide the url you are trying to use to get the json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the method `$.getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.blabla.com/testjson.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $('.result').append(val.Naam);
        alert(val.Naam);
    });
});
```

For more information, check the online doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

**PS:** Make sure that you added the website `www.blabla.com` to your whitelist exception.

For more information about Phonegap whitelist exceptions, check the online doc (the following link is for Phonegap / Cordova version 2.1.0): http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Done that, now i get nothing back, is it because i need to set up the cookies??

Comment: Did you add the website www.blabla.com to your whitelist exception?

Comment: @bdz: It has nothing to do with cookies. If the URL is external, you might have problems with the **same-origin policy**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

Comment: @Littm: I don't think "whitelist exception" is really helpful here, because it does not refer to a particular solution for SOP. What exactly are you talking about? CORS?

Comment: @FelixKling: You need to add whitelist exception with Phonegap, otherwise you won't have access to the external link. Check this link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: @Littm added whitelist exception still dont getting any results

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I forgot that it was tagged with phonegap (and I honestly have no experience with it). Please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will loop over each character of the param string "www.blabla.com/testjson", returning 'undefined' because by writing element.Naam you're trying to access a non existent property named 'Naam' of a character string.

You need to load the external json content by using an ajax call and parse it.

Here is a longer alternative to [Littm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12617257/1032370)'s answer if you're interested in handling errors too:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "data.json",
            data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),

            // dataType: "json",
            // the above requires 'application/json' as Content-Type headers
            // see 'reference A' in the footer notes
            // if you active this, please modify following code accordingly

            success: function (source, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(source);
                $.each(data, function(index, value)
                {
                    alert(index+" "+value.Naam);
                });
            },

            error: function(data)
            {
                // alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
    });
```

Notes:
1. [Reference A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query)

**EDIT:**
To get more info from error, add the following:

```
$(document).ajaxError(
    function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError)
    {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(ajaxSettings);
        console.log(thrownError);
    });
```

Then use the chrome console.

**EDIT:**
If I type the url you provided in a browser, I am redirected to a login page.
I think that your ajax code is getting this HTML document, too.

Try to check your session: you can add a div in your code and load the content of your url using curl inside this new div. Until you don't see your json code inside this div, your session variables are not working properly.
If curl will get correctly your file content, so will do ajax.

**EDIT:**
See? Your problem is to correctly login into the webservice from which you are trying to get the json file.

Your friend is right.
You have to set correctly your [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) in PHP which basically use [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661599/login-session-cookies-ajax-and-security) to retain session info.

Try to correctly:

```
session_start() ;
```

at the beginning of your php code, before using ajax.
References:
- php.net [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)
- [PHP session not working with JQuery Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564418/php-session-not-working-with-jquery-ajax)

**Please note that this will work only within the same domain**:
[Why jquery ajax not sending session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-jquery-ajax-not-sending-session-cookie)

If you are using different subdomains you can try to use

```
setcookie
```

References:
- php.net [setcookie](http://be.php.net/setcookie)
- [Cross domain cookie access (or session)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939294/1032370)


As far as I know there's no way to set cookies within different domains.
If you are in this situation, I suggest you to have a look at SimpleSAMLPHP descbribed here:
[cross domain cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095901/1032370)

**Good luck :)**

Comment: f.Event
currentTarget: HTMLDocument
data: undefined
delegateTarget: HTMLDocument
exclusive: undefined
handleObj: Object
isTrigger: true
jQuery17109108295564074069: true
namespace: ""
namespace_re: null
result: undefined
target: HTMLDocument
timeStamp: 1348756349438
type: "ajaxError"
__proto__: Object

Comment: I am getting the data from a webservice, the guy who build the webservice told me to use cookies.. curl is by using PHP, I cannot use PHP with phonegap :(

Comment: @bdz: see my last edit. Please note that your question has been closed due to the fact that your problem is too localized. Ask your webservice further assistance if you cannot find a way out.