# Ajax Post and PHP Session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do an ajax post for an e-commerce site.

So what I did was do an ajax post, when user click to "Add to cart" it will do the ajax post to the following php page with the code

```
<?php
include 'inc/session.php';
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

if($_POST['action'] == "add") {

    $_SESSION[$product_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
    $_SESSION["hello"] = "WORLD";
    //if add success return 111, else echo something else
    echo "111";
}
if($_POST['action'] == "remove") {

        $_SESSION[$product_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
    //if add success return 111, else echo something else
    echo "111";
}
?>
```

When I try to go to other page after the ajax post, I did

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

But it return empty array.

Everything is done within the same domain, same server.

**Thanks for helping!**

Below is my session file

```
<?php
ini_set("session.cache_limiter", "must-revalidate");
session_name("sess1");
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: can you also share your ajax script

Comment: @Baoky Plz make sure you have start session..

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564418/php-session-not-working-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: use print_r($_POST) to see if your post is coming through as expected.  If it's not, then the issue is likely with your javascript, not your php code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share your AJAX call.

Is is possible $_POST["action"] was never either "add" or "remove"?
If that is the case then your $_SESSION array would not be written.

You can check that by modifying the $_SESSION out of the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the page you're posting to make sure you add:

`session_start();`

Comment: I did do session_start.